# Convert data (or text?) to a string (or just to an array)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this, what I'm trying to do is convert the data to an array, but I think this doesn't work, so how can I convert the data to an string so then I can do the split?

```
$.ajax({
  url:"instructions.txt"
}).done(function(data){
  data.split("\n");
  alert(data);
})
```

This is my instructions.txt (UTF-8):

```
the-nap.mp4
0
7
19
25
```

Comment: What does `data` look like when it comes back from the request?

Comment: Can you show us the `instructions.txt`?

Comment: whats the encoding of the source file? utf8, ansi?

Comment: @MladenOršolić UTF-8

Comment: @AbraarArique I updated the question

Comment: @tymeJV I don't really know, but on the alert it shows as normal text

Comment: @LuisFelipe Can you try `data.toString().split("\n");`?

Comment: @AbraarArique It didn't work it just makes an an array of every character, not every line, kinda weird, don't know why that happens

Comment: @MladenOršolić still not working, it makes an array of every character, not line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
$.ajax({url:"instructions.txt"}).done(function(data){
  var myArray;
  myArray = data.toString().split("\n");
    for(var i in myArray) {
        alert(myArray[i]);
    }
});
```